# Wait authors message in async method discord.net c#

Tags: discord.net

I'm coding a bot with discord.net and I've run into one issue:
I have a SwitcherAsync method that accepts "SocketMessage" and I want to wait for a message from the author after calling one command.
I only found old examples that implement this task - https://dev.to/bizzycola/creating-a-discord-bot-with-c-net-core-and-dsharpplus-1obg
or https://github.com/XxshiftxX/discord-bot/blob/master/Nono%20Bot%20Dsharpplus/Voice.cs

But I am getting an error: 'DiscordSocketClient' does not contain a definition for 'GetInteractivityModule' and no accessible extension method

What can i make?

I don't understand how to work with GetInteractivityModule now.
I didn't find any information about this in the documentation.

Comment: You links are for DSharpPlus but you say you are using Discord.Net

Answer (score 0):

While this has always been possible through the MessageReceived listener using some temporary variables/files, I highly recommend you use discords /new/ interactions for this. In this case you're looking for the modal functionality, which will open a modal in the users client with text inputs to your liking.
These modals can be called in the context of any and all interactions with the exception of modals opening other modals

[Discord.NET docs -> Modals](https://discordnet.dev/guides/int_basics/modals/intro.html)